# trigger is not working on appending radio after windows onload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Why trigger is not working on all input radio?

Only working on that radio which is in body.**

```
    function addTaskUI(task){
            for (var key in task) {
                var keyUpperCase = key.toUpperCase();
                $("#radioButtons ul").append('<li><label for="'+key+'"><input type="radio" name="task" id="'+key+'" class="radioClass" value="'+key+'">'+keyUpperCase+'</label></li>');
            }   
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            $.getJSON("results-stress.json", addTaskUI);
            $(".radioClass").change(function () {
                alert("hello");
                alert(this.value);
            });
        }        
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <label for="all">
                                   <input type="radio" name="task" id="all" class="radioClass" value="all" checked="checked">ALL//this radio input is working good.
                                </label>                        
                            </li>
**//but when here code is appeared then not worked**</ul>
```

**I tried using name and class attribute but failed to resolved it**

**Is this any other way to handle this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way for elements which created on runtime.

```
window.onload = function() {
  $.getJSON("results-stress.json", addTaskUI);
  $(document).on('change', '.radioClass', function () {
    alert("hello");
    alert(this.value);
  });
}
```